# How to Color Code Gridview based on date values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to allow my Gridview control to display various colours based on conditions. A person has a date for a medical. I want the gridview to show a green color when the day has arrived. I want the date to show red when one day has passed on from the due date and orange like 7 days before the medical date. I have only managed to fix it for the green color which shows the medical on the day but I am having difficulties for the other conditions.

This is what i currently have. The first part of the If Statement works when i change the row to green based on the due date and the current date that is equal but I do not know how to set the if statement for the other conditions mentioned above. Please assist

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then


            Dim row As DataRow = (CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)).Row
            Dim DueDate As DateTime = row.Field(Of DateTime)(7)

            If DueDate.Date = DateTime.Today Then

                e.Row.Cells(0).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(0).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(1).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(1).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(2).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(2).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(4).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(4).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(5).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(6).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(6).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(7).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(7).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(8).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(8).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(9).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(9).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(10).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(10).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(11).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(11).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(12).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(12).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(13).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                e.Row.Cells(13).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White


            ElseIf Day(DateTime.Now) > 1 Then


                e.Row.Cells(0).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(0).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(1).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(1).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(2).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(2).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(4).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(4).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(5).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(6).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(6).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(7).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(7).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(8).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(8).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(9).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(9).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(10).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(10).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(11).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(11).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(12).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(12).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

                e.Row.Cells(13).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
                e.Row.Cells(13).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

            End If

        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a for loop 0 to 13 and remove your repetitions or color the whole row
2. to get a date which is 7 days later and check if sooner, compare to  `date.Now.addDays(7)`
3. to check if day passed, use `date.Now.addDays(-1)`

Comment: Thanks so much,  this has worked to my advantage @Devcon.

Comment: did you just mark a non related answer as answer instead of mine?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to make the entire row to be colored the same, then cellwise coloring is not required. Please use.

```
   e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
   e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Comment: Thanks for your expertise @Skaria Thomas, this has made my code more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Tevin. If it has helped you please upvote the answer, as it will be a motivation for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code behind method as follows:

Add the template column in GridView like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Due Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DueDate") %>'
            Style='<%# GetColorStyles(0, Eval("DueDate"))%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and use the following method for each cell:

```
Function GetColorStyles(ByVal cellindex As String, ByVal DueDate As DateTime) As String
    Dim RES As String = "color:#000000" 'default color
    If DueDate.Date = DateTime.Today Then
        RES = "color:#00FF00"
    ElseIf Day(DateTime.Now) > 1 Then
        RES = "color:#FF0000;"
    End If
    Return RES
End Function
```